# Problems with supporting tablets and handsets simultaneously - sounds

Tags: android, mute

I offer a mute option in my application, again in the settings screen, but although this mutes *my* sound effects, any clickable items that are pressed on the tablet still get the default click sound. How do I also stop the system clicks from happening? This is my current playSound method which won't play my sound effects with mMute has been set.

```
    try {
        streamVolume = mAudioManager
           .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    streamVolume = streamVolume
    / mAudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Null pointer returned from audio manager");
    }
    Integer soundToPlay = mSoundPoolMap.get(sound);
    if (streamVolume != 0.0f && soundToPlay != null && !mMute) {
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundPoolMap.get(sound), 
            streamVolume, streamVolume,
            1, 0, 1.0f);
    } else {
        Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, sound.toString() + " not found in sound pool map");
    }

}
```

Are there any other tips you can offer for sound handling in tablets? I assume that it's slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[View#setSoundEffectsEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSoundEffectsEnabled%28boolean%29) looks like one way, though it would require busy work building a set of all applicable views.

Comment: Hi nmr, I currently have a lot of my views defined within styles and themes so that may work and be quite quick to change. I'll try android:soundEffectsEnabled>false in the style for MyButton and see if that works.

Comment: Works a treat. Very glad I used themes/styles - I've barely had to change anything.